# Android http php json mysqli web services insert and retrieve data doesn't work

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, mysqli

I don't know where the bug is. Hope someone can help me.
Running it on real android device it returns "Incorrect user details" and howewer it doesn't send data to mysql server and then to database.
If I run php files from chrome browser it works perfectly.
I'm using wampp server as localhost.
Thanks very much in advance.

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wikibuyers.loginregister" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Login Activity**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegisterLink;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    tvRegisterLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);

    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.bLogin:
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            User user = new User(username,password);

            authenticate(user);

            userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
            break;

        case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));

            break;


    }
}

private void authenticate(User user){
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
    serverRequest.fetchUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            if (returnedUser == null){
                showErrorMessage();
            }else{
                logUserIn(returnedUser);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showErrorMessage(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user details");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}

private void logUserIn(User returnedUser){
    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

 }
}
```

**Register Activity**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bRegister;
EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, etPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    bRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bRegister:

            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            User user = new User(name,age,username,password);

            registerUser(user);

            break;
    }
}

private void registerUser(User user){
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
    serverRequest.storeUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,Login.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Server Requests Handler**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Domenico on 20/08/15.
 */



public class ServerRequest {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000*15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.***:8080/";

public ServerRequest (Context context){

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback  userCallback){

    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user,userCallback).execute();


}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback  userCallback){

    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user,userCallback).execute();

}

public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{

    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback  userCallback){
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS+"Register.php");



        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>{
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;
    User returnedUser ;
    public  fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");


        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
         try {
             JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

             if (jObject.length() == 0) {
                 returnedUser = null;
             } else {
                 String name = jObject.getString("name");
                 int age = jObject.getInt("age");
                 returnedUser = new User(name, age, user.username, user.password);

             }
         }catch (JSONException jE){
             jE.printStackTrace();
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnedUser;

        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
    }
}


}
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bLogout;
EditText etName, etAge, etUsername;
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);

    bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (autenthicate() == true){

        displayUserDetails();

    }else {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
    }

}

private void displayUserDetails(){
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    etUsername.setText(user.username);
    etName.setText(user.name);
    etAge.setText(user.age + "");

}

private boolean autenthicate(){

    return  userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bLogout:
            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**User class**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

/**
* Created by Domenico on 18/08/15.
*/
public class User {

String name, username, password;
int age;

public User (String name,int age,String username, String password) {

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

}

public User (String username,String password){

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.age = -1;
    this.name = "";

}

}
```

**UserLocalStore class**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
* Created by Domenico on 18/08/15.
*/
public class UserLocalStore {

public static final String SP_NAME = "userDetails";
SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;

public UserLocalStore (Context context){
    userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME,0);
}

public void storeUserData (User user){

   SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putString("name",user.name);
    spEditor.putString("username",user.username);
    spEditor.putString("password",user.password);
    spEditor.putInt("age", user.age);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public  User getLoggedInUser (){

    String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
    String username = userLocalDatabase.getString("username", "");
    String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password", "");
    int age = userLocalDatabase.getInt("age", -1);

    User storedUser = new User(name,age, username,password);

    return storedUser;

}

public void setUserLoggedIn (boolean loggedIn){

    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putBoolean("LoggedIn",loggedIn);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public boolean getUserLoggedIn(){
    if(userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("loggedIn",false) == true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

public  void clearUserData (){
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.clear();
    spEditor.commit();
}

}
```

**GetUserCallback interface**

```
package com.wikibuyers.loginregister;

/**
* Created by Domenico on 20/08/15.
*/
interface GetUserCallback {

public abstract void done (User returnedUser);

}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","loginregister");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}
else{
echo "Connessione effettuata";}  

if(isset($POST['name'])){$name = $_POST["name"];}else{$name="domenico";}
if(isset($POST['age'])){$age = $_POST["age"];}else{$age='42';}
if(isset($POST['password'])){$password =  $_POST["password"];}else{$password="pacecca";}
if(isset($POST['username'])){$username = $_POST["username"];}else{$username="dompac";}



$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username,  $password);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Fetch_User_Data.php**

```
<?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","loginregister");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$statement=mysqli_stmt_init($con);

if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")){

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username,  $password);
}




 $user = array();

 while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
      $user[0] = $name;
      $user[1] = $age;
      $user[2] = $username;
      $user[3] = $password;
 }


 echo json_encode ($user);



 mysqli_stmt_close($statement);


 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Where is your php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry. Issue was simple, even if it has gone me mad for a pair of weeks!
Look at fetch file "Fetch_User_Data.php" and then look at string where I call it as "FetchUserData.php" and you'll be done...